# Error with from pycaret.classification import *

Tags: python, importerror, pycaret

When I tried to run

```
from pycaret.classification import *
```

I received this error:

```
ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-83-a8cb12878b37> in <module>()
    ----> 1 from pycaret.classification import *

    8 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py in <module>()
         30 from ..utils._mask import _get_mask
         31 from ..utils.validation import _deprecate_positional_args
    ---> 32 from ..utils.fixes import sp_version, parse_version
         33 
         34 from ._pairwise_fast import _chi2_kernel_fast, _sparse_manhattan

    ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_version' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes' 
    (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled Python and re-installed it and now it works but I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

Try running this code `!pip install markupsafe==2.0.1`. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
import pycaret.classification
```

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

A possible resolution is to create a fresh environment. Sometimes conflicting packages cause issues so working with a fresh environment can help you determine whether this is the issue.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same issue and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71645272/importerror-cannot-import-name-markup-from-jinja2) solution helpful when working on google colab, although on Jupiter it didn't, so I created a virtual environment to work in, and it worked out smoothly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).