# ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

When I recently deployed my project that includes `Flask==1.0.2` and `Jinja2>=2.10.1`, I got the following error. It was running fine when I deployed it the previous day. I tried updating `Jinja2` but that didn't fix the issue.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/search_service/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from flasgger import Swagger
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flasgger/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .base import Swagger, Flasgger, NO_SANITIZER, BR_SANITIZER, MK_SANITIZER, LazyJSONEncoder  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flasgger/base.py", line 19, in <module>
    from flask import Blueprint
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
attrs>=19.1.0
boto3==1.17.23
click==7.0
itsdangerous==2.0.1
flasgger==0.9.5
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-RESTful>=0.3.6
flask-cors==3.0.8
gunicorn==20.1.0
Jinja2>=2.10.1
jsonschema>=3.0.1,<4.0
marshmallow>=3.0,<=3.6
marshmallow3-annotations>=1.0.0
pytz==2021.1
requests>=2.25.0
requests-aws4auth==1.1.0
statsd==3.2.1
typing==3.6.4
werkzeug>=2.0.0
wheel==0.36.2
itsdangerous==2.0.1
```

Answer (score 43):

As the import error comes from  flask `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py`

I tried to create a new Flask application using `Flask==1.0.2` and found that the error comes from this version of Flask when it used with `Jinja2>=2.10.1`.

But when you remove `Flask==1.0.2` and install `Flask==2.0.3`, everything works fine.

```
pip uninstall  Flask Jinja2
```

```
pip install Flask Jinja2
```

Dependencies

```
pip freeze
```

```
click==8.0.4
Flask==2.0.3
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
Werkzeug==2.0.3
```

Answer (score 24):

## Version 3.0.1

Regarding to the [documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/changes/?highlight=markup#version-3-0-1)

> Fixed calling deprecated jinja2.Markup without an argument. Use markupsafe.Markup instead. #1438

So to import Markup use the following code :

```py
>>> from markupsafe import Markup 
>>> Markup()
Markup('')
```

Comment: Markup, escape are now in ```jinja2.utils.markupsafe``` module.

Comment: That version can be installed with `pip install jinja2==3.0.1`

Comment: Right Dear @Dereckson, or  `pip install Jinja2` for the latest version.

Answer (score 10):

I solved a similar issue by running `pip install --upgrade <package-name>` on all individual packages of my flask app. This means that I did;

1. `pip install --upgrade babel`
2. `pip install --upgrade python-dateutil`
3. `pip install --upgrade flask-moment`
4. `pip install --upgrade flask-wtf`
5. `pip install --upgrade flask_sqlalchemy`

[requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShFES.png)

Comment: This answer worked for me. I have upgraded the jinja2 and markupsafe by running pip install --upgrade jinja2 and pip install --upgrade markupsafe then pip freeze > requirement.txt

Answer (score 8):

I guess this works:

```
from markupsafe import Markup
```

Saw it on [Github](https://github.com/stewartpark/Flask-JSGlue/pull/32/files)

Comment: the answer you are arguing can be supplemented with more information please add more information by editing and also read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: this seems to work but difficult to comprehend

Answer (score 5):

This might be a result of using a depreciated version of jinja2. In that case, uninstall jinja2 using `pip uninstall jinja2`
Then, install a stable version. You can install version 3 using `pip install jinja2==3.0`

Comment: This solved the cannot import Markup but now there is cannot import name json from itsdangerous

Comment: @KansaiRobot, do you find a better solution? I am having the same error. I have deployed successfully but in browsing, it shows an application error (cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2')

Comment: actually, I just gave up trying to use a requirements file. Instead I installed each necessary function manually one by one

Answer (score 3):

The actual [stable version of jinja is 3.x](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) try to update jinja:

1. Uninstall Jinja2==2.10.1

```py
pip uninstall jinja2
```

2. Install the latest version of jinja2

```py
pip install --upgrade jinja2
```

Comment: The actual version of Jinja2 is (3.1.1)  Stable release  25 th March 2022

Comment: tried it. have updated how i tried it, in Dockerfile in description. But didn't solve the issue

Comment: Right, you have to use the version 3.x of jinja2 and change the way to import, ```Markup``` and ```escape```  are now in ```jinja2.utils.markupsafe``` module.

Comment: i am not importing it, flask is importing it in run time.

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape`

Comment: Upgrade your flask version if it doesn't break your code. see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71647006/12042898)

Comment: tried this. did not work

Comment: Dear @KansaiRobot, what is your flask version ?

Comment: Sorry, I would answer that but it seems I just destroyed the virtual env and cannot recreate it. When I do I will post the version

Comment: @young_minds1, did you solve this import problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

file requirements.txt such as:

```
Flask==1.1.2  
Flask-Cors==3.0.8  
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8  
Jinja2==2.11.2 
MarkupSafe==1.1.1  
itsdangerous==1.1.0  
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

-> I think Flask version > 2.0 has this error!

Comment: or add lacation ='form': parse.add_argument('ID', location ='form) if Flask version > 2.0

Answer (score 1):

***run*** `pip uninstall Werkzeug jinja2`
***then*** `pip install Werkzeug==2.0.0`
***and*** `pip install jinja2==3.0`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Re: unclear. [For Noting] ... `pip install Werkzeug==2.0.0 jinja2==3.0`
 gives `ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
flask 2.2.3 requires Werkzeug>=2.2.2, but you have werkzeug 2.0.0 which is incompatible.`

Answer (score 0):

Hey what you need to do is update all the requirements files by running

```
pip install --upgrade <requirements.txt>
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade <Do it manually>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when using a python virtual environment, I had to remove flask and other libraries that were in the base python installation. I think some library I installed there was messing somehow with it.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR `from markupsafe import Markup`

---

> I tried updating Jinja2 but that didn't fix the issue.

For some, simply updating (or uninstall and install) jinja2 and Flask works.

However, the root problem is a 'pending' PR (pull request): [Fixed Markup import; it is now imported from markupsafe #32](https://github.com/stewartpark/Flask-JSGlue/pull/32/files)

To resolve this, do a `git` or simply edit the flask_jsglue.py`file in the`... lib\site-packages\flask_jsglue.py
edit `from jinja2 import Markup` to `from markupsafe import Markup`

```py
#from jinja2 import Markup
from markupsafe import Markup
```

@Ged-Flod provided an excellent [reference to the Jinja2 documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71645733/20107918): deprecation of `jinja2.Markup`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue when trying to deploy with Zappa. The solution I found was to run.

`pip install --platform=manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --target venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages flask markupsafe jinja2==3.0.3 --force-reinstall --upgrade`