# Import error for templated queries in Python using JinjaSql

Tags: python, jinja2, mysql-python

So, I'm trying to create SQL templates with certain parameters would change based on the call. I reviewed many other methods but I found the method using JinjaSql more suitable and readable for the requirement of my module.

I tried creating a class as below (code shortened) to create a templated list of queries.

```
from jinjasql import JinjaSql
j = JinjaSql(param_style='pyformat')


class QueryTemplate(object):
    def highest_pp_team_score(self, tour_name, year):
        params = {'tour_name': [], 'year': []}

        params['tour_name'].append(tour_name)
        params['year'].append(year)

        template = """
            SELECT 
              id.match_id,
              id.inning,
              id.team
            FROM 
              innings_deliveries as id
            WHERE 
              id.name LIKE {{ tour_name }}
              AND YEAR(id.start_date) = {{ year }} 
            """
        query, bind_params = j.prepare_query(template, params)
        return query % bind_params
```

... when I try and run, I get the below error. It's on the import itself.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2.utils'
```

After reading about the issue, I couldn't find any resolutions to my case but I did find a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71645272/importerror-cannot-import-name-markup-from-jinja2) with similar issue. It needed me to add few lines to the import. Since, the original issue was related to flask, I couldn't implement it to my case.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue in the library you are using. It has been reported on their issue tracker already, see https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/jinjasql/issues/50

What you could do is to downgrade your Jinja version to the one before **3.1.0** that brought those breaking changes of removing `Markup` and `escape`.

---

If you do have a *requirements.txt* file to install your dependencies, this is as simple as adding a line in it like

```
jinja2<3.1.0
```

And redo a

```sh
pip install --requirements requirements.txt
```

---

If you don't have such a file but are installing your packages with pip, you could do

```sh
pip install --upgrade 'jinja2<3.1.0'
```