# Jupyter scheduler fails with error "'jinja2' has no attribute 'Markup'"

Tags: jupyter-lab

I can't run files in jupyter lab using jupyter schedule. Every time the run fails, with the error

> module 'jinja2' has no attribute 'Markup'

If I just run the files in jupyter lab as normal, I get no error.

How can I resolve the markup error so I can run the files on a schedule?

Answer (score 0):

Similar error reported [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/export-to-html-problem-again/18119?u=fomightez), with solution suggestion [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12307#issuecomment-1084890899):

> "This is fixed by jupyter-server/jupyter_server#756 . If you run `pip install -U jupyter_server`, you should get a fix for this issue."

Comment: I tried that, but I still get the same issue. The packages now look like this: 
jupyter_server==2.7.2
jupyter_server_terminals==0.4.4
jupyterlab==4.0.5

Comment: What about your jinja2 and scheduler versions? I know [this isn't same as your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71645272/8508004) but you also didn't post your entire error traceback, which you should have done. I suspect something is old and importing or using markup in way no longer supported. Hard to tell given the limited information. How did you install things? Were they working? Can you just install the Anaconda Distribution and work with Jupyter and the scheduler there?